# Languages under plugin are not getting deployed to MPS

Tags: mps

I have built and added some new plugins to MPS and when I am trying to use them I am getting the following error **"The language is not deployed 'com.abc.plugin.implementation'"**

Anybody faced the similar problem and have a solution can help me?
MPS Version used: 2017.1.2
JDK: 1.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is a bug in MPS which is logged in youtrack as below:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/MPS-26437

Layout node for plugin places all modules of a group under a single folder. If there's a devkit among the modules, only devkits are loaded (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/MPS-25852), and other modules are ignored.

Unless we've got devkits deployed as regular modules, not simple files, MPS could place these devkit files separately when deploying a module as a workaround.

This problem is resolved and available with commit # `2edca430f054c908eb7606bad8ac6af46e0a7352`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean language plugins or other? If Yes can you find sources of your plugin (ctrl+alt+shift+S opens find module popup)? If there is no sources then plugin wasn't loaded. If you can find sources then probably some of language dependencies is not found (if any module in MPS has broken dependency then it won't be deployed). May be you build plugin with language, but didn't include it's runtime module.

Comment: Actually, it is a bug in MPS which is fixed.